# How to add http:// if it doesn't exist in the URL

Tags: php, regex

How can I add `http://` to a URL if it doesn't already include a protocol (e.g. `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://`)?

Example:

```
addhttp("google.com"); // http://google.com
addhttp("www.google.com"); // http://www.google.com
addhttp("google.com"); // http://google.com
addhttp("ftp://google.com"); // ftp://google.com
addhttp("https://google.com"); // https://google.com
addhttp("http://google.com"); // http://google.com
addhttp("rubbish"); // http://rubbish
```

Comment: If you had, `mozilla.org` alone, how would you know if it should be, `http`, `https` or `ftp`?

Comment: @Anthony: he says he wants to add "http://" if there's no other protocol.

Comment: @Anthony But when the user types the url without http:// or anything, do you expect it to be ftp:// or something?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

A modified version of @nickf code:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Recognizes `ftp://`, `ftps://`, `http://` and `https://` in a case insensitive way.

Comment: Having compared addhttp and addscheme below, I've come to the conclusion that addscheme is better in terms of performance:

`$url = "www.google.com";
$init = microtime(true);
for( $i = 1; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
 addScheme( $url );
}

echo  microtime(true) - $init;
echo "<BR>";

$init = microtime(true);
for( $i = 1; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
 addhttp( $url );
}
echo  microtime(true) - $init;
`

Comment: What if url begins with '//'?

Answer (score 149):

At the time of writing, none of the answers used a built-in function for this:

```
function addScheme($url, $scheme = 'http://')
{
  return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === null ?
    $scheme . $url : $url;
}

echo addScheme('google.com'); // "http://google.com"
echo addScheme('https://google.com'); // "https://google.com"
```

See also: [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/parse_url)

Comment: This should be the selected answer - why roll your own when the language has native support? Nice work.

Comment: One improvement that could be made with this function is checking to see if the field has a  value so it is not adding an http to an empty field.

Comment: This doesn't work with relative protocols. e.g. `echo addScheme('//google.com');`

Comment: @Taylan Yeah, you would have to `ltrim($url, '/')`

Answer (score 51):

Simply check if there is a protocol (delineated by "://") and add "http://" if there isn't.

```
if (false === strpos($url, '://')) {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
```

**Note**: This may be a simple and straightforward solution, but [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-the-url/14701491#14701491) using `parse_url` is almost as simple and much more robust. You should probably use that one.

Answer (score 4):

The *best answer* for this would be something like this:

```
function addScheme($url, $scheme="http://" )
{
  return $url = empty(parse_url($url)['scheme']) ? $scheme . ltrim($url, '/') : $url;
}
// Test below
$url = 'google.com';
echo addScheme($url,"ftp://"); // "https://google.com"
echo addScheme('google.com'); // "http://google.com"
echo addScheme('https://google.com'); // "https://google.com"
```

The protocol flexible, so the same function can be used with ftp, https, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Scan the string for `://`. If it does not have it, prepend `http://` to the string... Everything else just use the string as is.

This will work unless you have a rubbish input string.

Comment: i'de prefer a regex version :)

Comment: Don't be too quick on regex. Regex tends to be hard to read and it could introduce another problem/bug once the problem grows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is not watertight<sup>1</sup>, but it might be good enough:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("@^[hf]tt?ps?://@", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

<sub>1. That is, prefixes like "fttps://" are treated as valid.</sub>

Comment: This would match (ergo return true and if would evaluate to false) weird combinations.. like htps, fttps, fttp, htp, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[nickf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-the-url/2762066#2762066) modified:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("@^https?://@i", $url) && !preg_match("@^ftps?://@i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: I believe `ftps://` is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (!preg_match("/^(http|ftp):/", $_POST['url'])) {
        $_POST['url'] = 'http://'.$_POST['url'];
    }
    $url = $_POST['url'];
?>
```

This code will add *http://* to the URL if it’s not there.