# How can I check if 'http://' is in the variable, and if not, add it?

Tags: php

Basically, I'm using `gethostbyname()` to get the IP address of the specified URL, using `parse_url()` to determine the specific domain. However, this doesn't work if `http://` is not in the URL (unless I'm missing an option)

So how can I check if `http://` is in the URL, and if not, add it appropriately?

Or if have a better alternative, I'd like to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
  $url = [some url here];
  if(substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://') {
     $url = 'http://' . $url;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, strictly speaking, you need to consider https as well, and maybe even ftp and mailto depending on what you are doing.
You might want to check for a ':' first, without one you DEFINITELY don't have a protocol, and could skip the rest, with one you might have a protocol, or maybe a port specification.

```
  <?php 
  $url = [some url here]; 
  if(substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://') { 
      if(substr($url, 0, 8) != 'https://') { 
         $url = 'http://' . $url; 
      } 
  } 

?>
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
if(!preg_match('/http[s]?:\/\//', $url, $matches)) $url = 'http://'.$url;
```

Answer (score -4):

`if (strpos("http://", $url) === "true"){
action
};`

Comment: This comparison will not work. strpos returns an integer on success, and boolean `false` if the string is not found. It will not ever return boolean `true` and certainly not string `'true'`. `if (strpos("http://", $url) !== false)` would test if it was found in the whole string, or to see if it's at the start of the string, `if (strpos("http://", $url) === 0)`