# URL filter with str_replace

Tags: php

I've input field where visitor will have to enter URL and some may enter just `www.some_site.com` or `http://www.some_site.com` or `https://www.some_site.com`
or even `some_site.com`.

i want no matter they entered is to make the output like `http://www.some_site.com`

will i use `str_replace` but how.

~ any help or idea else.

Comment: You should use Regex instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388061/php-format-a-website-url-with-http-if-not-present-more-of-a-string-thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code

```
//$url = "https://www.google.com";
$url = "http://www.google.com";
//$url = "google.com";

echo convertUrl( $url); 

function convertUrl ( $url ) { 
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  //print_r( $parts);
  $returl = ""; 
  if ( empty($parts['scheme']) ) { 
    $returl = "http://" . $parts['path'];
  } else if ( $parts['scheme'] == 'https') {
    $returl = "http://" . $parts['host'];
  } else {
    $returl = $url;
  }

  return $returl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
if ($result['scheme'] == '' || $result['scheme'] == 'https') {
    $result['scheme'] = 'http';
}
```

Then put it back together using [http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function unifyUrl($sUrl){
 $exp = explode('://', $sUrl);
        if(count($exp) > 1)//means we have http or https
            $url = $exp[1];
        else
            $url = $exp[0];

        if(!preg_match('/^www\./', $url))//we are lack of www. in the beginning
            $url = 'www.'.$url;

        return 'http://'.$url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myURL = 'www.some_site.com/something_else/else/else.php'; //the normal URL
$myURL = explode('.some_site.com', $myURL); //break down the url by '.some_site.com'
$myURL = 'http://www.some_site.com/' . $myURL[1]; //add 'http://www.some_site.com/' and then add 'something_else/else/else.php'
echo $myURL;// OUTPUT: http://www.some_site.com//something_else/else/else.php
```