# Add http:// prefix to URL when missing

Tags: php, http, html, anchor, href

Hello I have a very simple code

```
<a href="'.$aProfileInfo['Website'].'" target="_self">
    <div class="callButton">Website</div>
</a>
```

The problem is that if the user does not enter http:// the link will then point to my website and not to the external website as it should.

How do I check in PHP if the user has not entered http:// and automatically add it when it is not there?

Comment: Also, _please_ make sure that you are escaping user input before inserting it into html. See [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: You can simplify David's answer to work on one line (so you can put it inline with your HTML). See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24482058/1101095

Comment: @Nate actually, you can simplify it even further than that. Also the regular expression way can be a one-liner as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31549463/1572938

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple solution which may not work in all cases (i.e. 'https://'):

```
if (strpos($aProfileInfo['Website'],'http://') === false){
    $aProfileInfo['Website'] = 'http://'.$aProfileInfo['Website'];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `strpos` require haystack first, needle second?

Answer (score 55):

I think you'd better use the built in function `parse_url()` which returns an associative array with its components

something like this will work for you:

```
 if  ( $ret = parse_url($url) ) {

      if ( !isset($ret["scheme"]) )
       {
       $url = "http://{$url}";
       }
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way!

Comment: The regex answer is cool, but I agree that this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Will fail if user input is something like: **foo:bar@foobar/p?arg=val#a**

« foo » will be interpreted as the scheme.

Comment: You could simply concatenate `//` instead of `http` to use current page's scheme (http / https).

Comment: I guess this will force the same protocol of the site is coming from, so if your site is under https:// all link will became https:// and they may not has an  https:// url

Comment: I killed my regex answer. This is the better answer. It will maintain the scheme if it is there and if not it will assume and prefix the url with `http://`. +1

Answer (score 33):

I personally use this, which is partially taken from the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$scheme = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if (empty($scheme))
    $link = 'https://' . ltrim($link, '/');
```

Comment: This should definitely be the first answer. Perfect!

Comment: With HTTPS being the new standard this should be updated to https

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways of tackling this problem: url parsing and regular expressions.

Some will say url parsing is *right*, but regular expressions work just as well in this case. I like being able to have simple one-liners for things like this especially because this would be a common occurrence in template files where you may need a one-liner inside an echo statement to maintain readability.

## Regular Expressions

We can do this in a single function call with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
preg_replace('/^(?!https?:\/\/)/', 'http://', $aProfileInfo['Website'])
```

This uses a `negative lookahead` at the beginning of the string that looks for `http://` or `https://`. If either are found, the replace doesn't happen. If they **aren't** found, it replaces the beginning of the string (0 characters) with `http://` essentially prepending this to the string without modifying it.

In context:

```
<a href="'. preg_replace('/^(?!https?:\/\/)/', 'http://', $aProfileInfo['Website']).'" target="_self">
    <div class="callButton">Website</div>
</a>
```

## URL Parsing

```
(parse_url($aProfileInfo['Website'], PHP_URL_SCHEME) ? '' : 'http://') . $aProfileInfo['Website']
```

What this does is find out if a scheme is present on the link throught `parse_url($aProfileInfo['Website'], PHP_URL_SCHEME)`. Then using a ternary operator, it will either output `''` if there was one found or `'http://'` if one wasn't found. Then it appends the link onto that.

In context:

```
<a href="'.((parse_url($aProfileInfo['Website'], PHP_URL_SCHEME) ? '' : 'http://') . $aProfileInfo['Website']).'" target="_self">
    <div class="callButton">Website</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Your regex is smart that it preserves `https://` however it doesn't work with relative urls such as `//www.example.com`. It also appends `http://` onto `ftp://` or other protocols. Try this instead: `preg_replace('/^\/\/|^(?!https?:)(?!ftps?:)/', 'http://', $src)` (note: you can remove the check for ftp if you dont need it)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
// Trim trailing whitespace
$aProfileInfo['Website'] = trim($aProfileInfo['Website']);

// Test if the string begins with "http://"
if (strpos($aProfileInfo['Website'], 'http://') !== 0) {
  $aProfileInfo['Website'] = 'http://' . $aProfileInfo['Website'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function as a general *if nothing from the array is found in the string* append something to it.

```
function httpify($link, $append = 'http://', $allowed = array('http://', 'https://')){

  $found = false;
  foreach($allowed as $protocol)
    if(strpos($link, $protocol) !== 0)
      $found = true;

  if($found)
    return $link;
  return $append.$link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also may take into account that "http(s)" must be at the beginning of the url:

```
if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $aProfileInfo['Website']) === 0) {
    $aProfileInfo['Website'] = 'http://'.$aProfileInfo['Website'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (!strpos($aProfileInfo['Website'], 'http://')) {
    $aProfileInfo['Website'] = 'http://' . $aProfileInfo['Website'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example with [string subtraction](https://www.php.net/substr):

```
$changeLink = $myRow->site_url;
  if(substr($changeLink, 0, 7) != 'http://') {
     $changeLink = 'http://' . $changeLink;  
}
```

// ....

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $changeLink . "\" target=\"_blank\"></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing/6705427#6705427) is the proper way to do this, but it can be simplified like this:

```
parse_url($aProfileInfo['Website'], PHP_URL_SCHEME)==''?'http://'.$aProfileInfo['Website']:$aProfileInfo['Website']
```