# insert a http:// component into a POST variable

Tags: php

How can I add a 'http://' component to a post variable so that it automatically adds that part so if someone submits: 'www.google.com' is will register as http://www.google.com. Heres the code I have so far:

```
$domain = '<a target="_blank" href="' .$_POST['domain'] . '">' . $_POST['domain'] .'</a>';
```

so where do I insert the 'http://'? I have tried a few variations with no success perhaps     someone can enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: `href="http://'.$_POST['domain'].'"`. Simples!

Comment: Have you tried `...href="http://' . $_POST['domain'] . '...`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add http:// prefix to URL when missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing)

Comment: There are a couple of correct answers up now, but note that this has nothing to do with it being a POST variable. You an assign the POST variable to a regular variable and manipulate it in any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but is this what you want to do?

```
$domain = '<a target="_blank" href="http://' .$_POST['domain'] . '">' . $_POST['domain'] .'</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I had tried that but I must have done a typo first time. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  $length = strlen($needle);
  return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}

$address = startsWith($_POST['domain'], 'http://') ? $_POST['domain'] : 'http://' . $_POST['domain'];

$domain = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $address . '">' . $_POST['domain'] .'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href = "http://'.$_POST['domain'].'";
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I had tried that but I must have done a typo first time. thanks.