# Echo only a part of an URL (string)

Tags: php

I have an input field where the user can type an URL. He could type the URL in many different ways, for example:

- www.example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- example.com/index.php

No matter how he types it, I want to echo it like this: **example.com**

Only when it is an sub domain, then it should look like this: **subdomain.example.com**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allow myself to answer my own question:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/index.php';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://|www.#', '', rtrim($url,'/'));
echo (strpos($str,'/') !== false) ? strstr($str, '/', true) : $str;
```

You can define $url however you want. The result is always **example.com**

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with the `PHP_URL_HOST` component as the second parameter:

```
$url = 'example.com/index.php';
if (preg_match("#https?://#", $url) === 0) {
    $url = 'http://'.$url;
}
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

(I had some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing) to make sure there is always a protocol attached to the URL.)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't that qualified as a "seriously malformed url". Let me modify this to work around that.

Comment: @JohnConde From the man page: Tip

Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Comment: to be fair he is looking for 2 strings, `http` OR `https`

Comment: @Dagon, yeah, but he doesn't need to, since one of the strings is a substring of the other. The tip is valid.

Comment: but then I guess it makes sense to check for the entire thing in case "http" is part of the domain. I'll shut up now.

Comment: @Dagon Personally I'd just strpos($url,"://");