# Add http:// prefix to URL when it is missing

Tags: php

Hello Guys im using this to Add http:// prefix to Url when missing. The problem is that he add it to the other Url's where i have http:// already.

```
foreach($result as $key => &$value)
    {

        if  (strpos($sample['Internetadress'], 'http://') === false){
            $sample['Internetadress'] = 'http://' .$sample['Internetadress'];
            }

    }
```

1. i want that he doesnt edit it when it exist.
2. i want that he doesnt add it when there is no URL.

Sorry about my english im from Germany :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add http:// prefix to URL when missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing)

Comment: The solution code to that dupe is exactly what the OP has lol. OP can you provide a data example of one which would cause a double `http://`. My first thoughts are that your url will look like `http://https://`

Comment: Your code should cover your first point.

Comment: What about if its already https://?

Answer (score 1):

Your code shoud cover your first point (when http exist don't change the URL), if not provide us a sample url that you want to modify.

For the second point you just make another check like this:

```
<?php
$sample['Internetadress']='www.example.com';

if  (strpos($sample['Internetadress'], 'http://') === false && trim($sample['Internetadress'])!==''){
    if(strpos($sample['Internetadress'], 'https://') === false){
        $sample['Internetadress'] = 'http://' .$sample['Internetadress'];
    }
}


echo $sample['Internetadress'];
```

Comment: Should probably also be `trim($sample['Internetadress']) !== ''` in case it's got a random space or something in.

Comment: It works but when the existing URL begins with https:// hes still add http://. All the other problems are solved. Thx for this

Comment: Ah that's another thing you did not mention that you are going to have https://, you only said http and empty. Will modify it to make it work

Comment: Yes you right. Sorry about that, i recognized the problem with https:// right now.

Comment: I will wait for your modify. Thx

Comment: Ok, i guess there is a delay then.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case a little regex is a good solution:

```
$urls = [
    'http://www.example.com',
    'foo.bar.com',
    'https://example.com',
    'www.example.com'
];

foreach ($urls as &$url) {
    $url = preg_replace('/^(?!http)/i', 'http://', $url);
}
```

The values in `$urls` after the loop are:

```
[
    "http://www.example.com",
    "http://foo.bar.com",
    "https://example.com",
    "http://www.example.com"
]
```

Also instead of using a foreach loop and passing the values by reference you could use a [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
$urls = array_map(function($url) {
    return preg_replace('/^(?!http)/i', 'http://', $url);
}, $urls);
```