# Laravel href link not working if URL doesn‘t contain string 'http'

Tags: html, laravel, http, href

I have this a tag

```
<a href="{{ $organization->website }}">Link</a>
```

If $organization->website is a url that contains http:// or https:// at the start, the link will work.

However, if it doesn't, the link will bring me to something like this

http://localhost/public/www.google.com instead of www.google.com

I know that you can use // so that links without http will work, like this

```
<a href="//{{ $organization->website }}">Link</a>
```

However, links with http:// or https:// at the start will now not work instead.

Is there a solution that can work with both (URLs with no http and URLs with http)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add http:// prefix to URL when missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240414/add-http-prefix-to-url-when-missing)

Comment: I wouldn't use the accepted answer in that since it only looks for http://, but the other answers look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace https://, http:// or / by just // which would do what you

like:

```
'//' . (strpos($url, '//') !== false ? substr($url, strpos($url, '//') + 2) : ltrim($url, '/'))
```

therefore it would be:

```
<a href="{{ '//' . (strpos($organization->website, '//') !== false ? substr($organization->website, strpos($organization->website, '//') + 2) : ltrim($organization->website, '/')) }}">Link</a>
```

https://www.google.com, http://www.google.com, //www.google.com, /www.google.com or www.google.com will be converted to //www.google.com which I believe is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it in twig templating, using OctoberCMS (laravel):

eventen.about_url|slice(0, 4) looks for 'http' in the beginning of the url variable, if its there it uses that link as it is, if not, it adds // before the link.

```
{% if eventen.about_url|slice(0, 4)=='http' %}
    <a href="{{eventen.about_url}}" target="_blank">
       Link
     </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="//{{eventen.about_url}}" target="_blank">
       Link
    </a>
{% endif %}
```