# Determining the Vimeo source by URL (regex)

Tags: php, regex, vimeo

Okay, here's a fun one.

I need to figure out what source a user is referencing when entering a copy and pasted Vimeo URL into an input box. For those that are unfamiliar, Vimeo currently has 4 different sources that are accessible through their simple API:

### Videos belonging to a user

**Valid URL structure:** http://vimeo.com/user3825208 or https://vimeo.com/davekiss

### Videos belonging to a group

**Valid URL structure:** http://vimeo.com/groups/eos550d or https://vimeo.com/groups/162

### Videos belonging to a channel

**Valid URL structure:** http://vimeo.com/channels/hd or https://vimeo.com/channels/201

### Videos belonging to an album

**Valid URL structure:** http://vimeo.com/album/1919683 or https://vimeo.com/album/mycustomname

So basically, I want to be able to run the URL into a function which will tell me what source the URL belongs to.

I've been using this for videos belonging to a user, but now I need to expand to all sources.

`sscanf(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/%d', $video_id);`

Maybe I should do this four times? `preg_match('???', $url);`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show what regex you currently have

Comment: My approach has been for the user to tell me what they have been using in another dropdown box (group, album, channel, or username) but I want to simplify it. I'm pretty poor with regex, but I got `/^(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(clip\:)?(\d+).*$/` working with single clips previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions:

```
function discoverVimeo($url)
{
    if ((($url = parse_url($url)) !== false) && (preg_match('~vimeo[.]com$~', $url['host']) > 0))
    {
        $url = array_filter(explode('/', $url['path']), 'strlen');

        if (in_array($url[0], array('album', 'channels', 'groups')) !== true)
        {
            array_unshift($url, 'users');
        }

        return array('type' => rtrim(array_shift($url), 's'), 'id' => array_shift($url));
    }

    return false;
}
```

The following will return an array, with an index `id` and another index `type`, that will be one of:

- `user`
- `album`
- `channel`
- `group`

Comment: It'll take me a bit to test this, but I'll report back. Thanks for your time!

Comment: 2 things: I noticed the index of the $url to check should be `$url[1]` instead of `$url[0]`. Also, if the user omits the `http://` or `https://`, this fails. Is there any way to account for that as well?

Comment: @DaveKiss: Are you sure about the index? Did you try the latest version where I use `array_filter`? Because it should be 0... Regarding the protocol, you can do `$url = sprintf('http://%s', preg_replace('~^https?://~i', '', $url));` right before the `parse_url` call.

Comment: @DaveKiss: Regarding the protocol, you can also use http://stackoverflow.com/a/2762083/89771.

Answer (score 1):

i would preg_match() the following regex patterns (in this order):

```
$channel_regex = '%vimeo\.com/channels/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%/i';
$group_regex = '%vimeo\.com/groups/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%/i';
$album_regex = '%vimeo\.com/album/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%/i';
$user_regex = '%vimeo\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%/i';
```

this will regex match for:

```
vimeo.com/channels/...grab_this_data...
vimeo.com/groups/...grab_this_data...
vimeo.com/albums/...grab_this_data...
```

and if all of those preg_matches fail, (therefore a user URL), it will grab whatever is in the url:

```
vimeo.com/...grab_this_data...
```

good luck.