# Hyperlink to an exterior URL retrieved from database using TWIG

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.0.19. I'm trying to create a hyperlink to an external URL, which is retrieved from a database.

I tried doing this

```
<td><a href="{{dominio.url}}">{{dominio.url}}</a></td>
```

but the path I get is a relative path to the URL *inside* the base URL example "localhost/web/www.tralalalala.com" instead of just "www.tralalalala.com".

How do I do this?

Comment: replace `localhost/web/` whenever you have that variable `dominio.url`... and when you upload it to server, keep only the `dominio.url` and remove that replace method :D otherwise, edit .htaccess files!

Comment: if dominio.url is just www.tralalala.com you need to do `<td><a href="http://{{dominio.url}}">{{dominio.url}}</a></td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to build your own Twig filter.

If your url aldready have `http://`, don't add it, otherwise, add it.

Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) for how-tos.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a concrete example of what *Pierrickouw* is suggesting:

Create a Twig extension or filter under `src/Twig`, and call it for example `ExternalLinkFilter`. Define the class as follows:

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class ExternalLinkFilter extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('external_link', array($this, 'externalLinkFilter')),
        );
    }

    /* source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2762083/3924118 */
    public function externalLinkFilter($url)
    {
        if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
        }

        return $url;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'external_link_filter';
    }
}

?>
```

Now, you should register this class as a service in `config/services.yml` as follows:

```
services:

    # other services

    app.twig.external_link:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\ExternalLinkFilter
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now you can simply use the filter called `external_link` as you would use any Twig's default one, e.g.:

```
...

<a href="{{check.hostname | external_link }}"> {{check.hostname}}</a>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

A symfony 5 version of nbro's answer will be:
(This will take care of all kind of url that is read from the db)

source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

in src/Twig create the file

```
    <?php 

    namespace App\Twig;

    use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
    use Twig\TwigFilter;

    class ExternalLinkFilter extends AbstractExtension
    {
        public function getFilters()
        {
            return array(
                new TwigFilter('external_link', array($this, 'externalLinkFilter')),
            );
        }

        /* source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2762083/3924118 */
        public function externalLinkFilter($url)
        {
            if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
                $url = "http://" . $url;
            }

            return $url;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'external_link_filter';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

You don't need to register it as a service. Symfony 5 will notice the presence of that Twig extension

Use it in twig template as suggested by @nbro

```
    <a href="{{check.hostname | external_link }}"> {{check.hostname}}</a>
```