# How can I change the scheme of a URL with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add http:// if it’s not exists in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url)

Say I want to match a URL that may have either `http://`, `https://` or neither in it. When I replace it, I want to have `https://` at the front if it was there, but if it was `http://` or nothing I want to have `http://` at the beginning.

I can't figure out how to figure this out with a preg_match expression, or for the non-PHP inclined, a search and replace PHP function.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html might hold your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), and write a function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you want a regex solution.

`preg_replace('|^(?:http(s)?://)?(.+)$|', 'http\\1://\\2', $url);`

Though i would probably use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and put it back together.

Comment: My problem lies with a URL such as `www.stackoveflow.com` without any http:// or https://

Comment: did you even try it? `echo preg_replace('|^(?:http(s)?://)?(.+)$|', 'http\\1://\\2', 'www.stackoverflow.com');`