# Php: retrieving url from db and redirecting to url

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database that stores the url example facebook.com i dispalyed the value in my table and i posted the same value in a href

```
            <a href="<?php echo $url['url']; ?>" target="_blank">
            <?php echo $fet_2['urlname']; ?></a>
```

so when i click the urll is opening in new tab like domain.COM/folder/folder/www.facebook.com and the fb page is not loaded. i want to load the fb page when i click the name. please help me

Comment: Append http:// to your href...

Comment: No problem -- glad we could help.  Posted some additional information to consider.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you are missing the `http://` from the URL, and that's why you are directed to inside the domain looking for that page.

You can solve it like this.

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $url['url']; ?>" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, make sure the href has an "http://" in the URL.  If not, the site will try to open in your current domain.

If some of the URLs in your database have the http://, then you need to do a check before prepending.  Use something like this:

[How to add http:// if it's not exists in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url)

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: `magnet://` ;) `\w+://` would be more flexible, but this will probably cover all the cases OP has in mind anyway.