# Wordpress custom field echoing whole URL

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is as below:

```
<?php   
if( get_field( "facebook" ) !== '' ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo the_field('facebook'); ?>">Facebook</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Instead of echoing the field's value which is (wwww.facebook.com), it's echoing it relative to the wordpress website.

Also, is my code efficient? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Edit: What finally worked for me:

```
<?php
$website =  (get_field('website'));
if(!empty($website)){
$final_url = (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $website))? 'http://'.$website: $website;
echo "<a href=\"$final_url\">$final_url</a>" . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `http://` on the beggining to make external URLS

```
<a href="http://<?php echo the_field('facebook'); ?>">Facebook</a>
```

or add `http://` on your advanced custom field in the admin

***EDIT:***

here is your final code:

```
$url = the_field('facebook');

if($url!=""){
    $final_url = (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url))? 'http://'.$url: $url;
    echo '<a href="'.$final_url.'">Facebook</a><br/>';
}
```

NOTE:

- your data `wwww.facebook.com` has excess w
- i appended the code given by @feeela so it would check if `http://` is present, thanks to @feeela

Comment: …and see also [How to add http:// if it's not exists in the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url)

Comment: Well, if you can't decide in the application whether to link to another website or to your own, you may have a problem.

Comment: How can I add a line break only if the custom field is present? All that I have tried so far adds space regardless of whether the custom field is empty or filled.

Comment: @feeela: yeah i realized it should always be external given this situation (facebook link). you are right

Comment: @reikyoushin, sorry if I'm being a total noob here. But I've started learning PHP 2 weeks ago.

Comment: no problem. is it working now or are there other problems you are encountering?

Comment: I've just edited the code above. I'm trying to add the <br> tag only if the custom field is processed. Otherwise, to skip to the next argument.

Comment: you want the <br/> to follow the <a> tag? just look at my new edit then

Comment: I think my main problem is with the name, address, phone, etc fields. They're passing a <br> tag regardless of whether the field is there or not. I'd appreciate any general notes on how to make the above code more efficient. Is it bad style to keep using "echo.. "?

Comment: you're using advanced custom fields right? you should set the text field's formatting to `None` instead of `HTML`. you would see that on the plugin so it will not add auto-line breaks, see [screenshot](http://oi39.tinypic.com/33c436e.jpg)

Comment: I'm using advanced custom fields. Changed the formatting to none. The problem is, even if the field is empty, the line break from IF statement is echoed: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25u7h52&s=5.

Comment: i would need to have a source code for that besides the image.. though.

Comment: and what does `var_dump(the_field('facebook'));` output?

Comment: @reikyoushin Thanks for all your help! I've ended up using !empty, the code that finally worked for me is posted above as an edit.