# Using file_get_contents to parse webpage data

Tags: php

I am parsing webpage data using `` ` PHP function. 
But problem with this is it gives error when url starts from ``www.`

```
( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(www.iiit.ac.in): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\wamp\www\test.php on line 63
```

Here is the demo for this code: [Link to DEMO](http://codepad.org/LRJkxRI0)

```
<?php
$url= 'www.facebook.com';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;

echo "<br/>Using http";

$url= 'https://www.facebook.com';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a solution to your problem please try executing the following alternative source code snippet

```
<?php
 $url= 'http://www.facebook.com';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 
 echo $result;  
?>
```

Comment: it gives error  `


Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() on line 3


` P.S. http://codepad.org/nXwKSnSn

Comment: please try executing the above code snippet into your local server and also enable curl extension in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the protocol. PHP won't assume a protocol.

If you don't control these strings, check for a protocol when they're entered to validate. Either that or add `http://` if they're not present.

Comment: Thanks! but we cant control users. They make query with `www.` always. So there is not scope to deal with such query directly in above case, right? How to append `http://` before url if not present?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook probably wants a user agent, see [PHP file_get_contents() and headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers)

Validate the url with a regex, see [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Or this, might be better for your situation:

[How to add http:// if it's not exists in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check it the url starts with http:// or https:// with below.

```
$url = 'www.facebok.com';
if (substr($url, 0, 7) !== 'http://' && substr($url, 0, 8) !== 'https://') {
   $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
echo $url;
```

above would return http://www.facebook.com hope this helps.