# PHP string replace when string is not

Tags: php, str-replace

When href="something/blah/" I need to add the domain $site/something/blah

When href="/someething/blah" I need to add the domain $site/something/blah

when href="http:// I need to do nothing.

when href="www.blah.com I need to add http://

**Updated for more specific situation**

Simply showing me code to add http:// when it does not exist will not help as there are to many case situations that don't apply to just http://

Comment: That code will already replace `href` that doesn't start with `http://`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you just do the reverse and check if it doesn't exist and add to it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url

Comment: Basically you want to add htttp:// in href when it does not exist?

Comment: @FirstOne No it wont that code will only replace href="/ if href="h it will not be replace. nor if href="w nor if href="anything other than href="/

Comment: @Fred-ii- that was precisely the question - how do I do a str_replace when a pattern doesn't exist instead of when a pattern does exist??

Comment: That link I gave you has quite a few examples Bruce.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't just want to add http:// where its missing.